# About GRANT statement for user creation

Tags: mysql

I am new to databases, learning MySQL through a textbook.

My doubts are regarding `grant` statement.

I am learning on a localhost environment (both server and clieat are my own system).

**FIRST DOUBT**

If I create a new user account by

```
 GRANT ALL on mydb.* TO 'violetkiwi' IDENTIFIED BY '12345';
```

Command executed successfully.  When I tried to log into this account by

```
mysql -u violetkiwi -p

Access denied for user 'violetkiwi'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

If I specify @'localhost' in `GRANT ALL` issue is solved:

```
 GRANT ALL on mydb.* TO 'violetkiwi'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '12345';
```

Is `@'localhost'` or `@'IP ADDRESS'` compulsory in `GRANT ALL` user account creation?

**SECOND DOUBT** is IPADDRESS specification in `GRANT ALL` for user account

Consider I have to connect to MySQL server over the internet.

How can I achieve connection to MySQL server through ADSL modem which doesnt have static IP to specify during user account creation with `GRANT ALL`?

**THIRD DOUBT**

Sometimes I can access MySQL without specifying -p:

```
mysql -u root;

mysql -u violetkiwi;
```

but I can't perform operations on DB. Why this access is provided without specifying password? Is it a bug in my system? Does it have a purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's look at the way you created the user.

EXAMPLE : I have a database called `zipcodes`. I will create a user called `rolando`

```
mysql> grant all on zipcodes.* to rolando identified by 'blahblah';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.04 sec)

mysql> show grants for rolando;
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for rolando@%                                                                                   |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'rolando'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*446525BB82B5E22BD9E525261D37C494F623C52B' |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `zipcodes`.* TO 'rolando'@'%'                                                  |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I specified `rolando` without an IP or netblock. By defualt, '%' is used. That should allow remote IP address to login.

You said you tried to login to your account with

```
 mysql -u violetkiwi -p
```

Why did this not work? Simply put, you were not connecting remotely. You created the user `violetkiwi@'%'`. You should create the user `violetkiwi@localhost`. Then, it can cleanly connect.

You need to make sure your mysql authentication scheme has been cleaned up

[**MySQL 5.0 Certification Study Guide says on Page 498 Paragraph 6**](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0672328127) in its bulletpoints brings out how to cleanup the authentication process:

> On Unix, MySQL comes with a mysql_secure_installation script that can
>   perform several helpful security-related operations on your
>   installation. The script has the following capabilities:
>
> - Set a password for the root accounts
> - Remove any remotely accessible root accounts.
> - Remove the anonymous user accounts. This improves security because
>     it prevents the possibility of anyone connecting to the MySQL server
>     as root from a remote host. The results is that anyone who wants to
>     connect as root must first be able to log in on the server host, which
>     provides an additional barrier against attack.
> - Remove the test database (If you remove the anonymous accounts, you
>     might also want to remove the test database to which they have
>     access).

A remotely accessible account is an account whose host is `%` which allows anyone and his grandmother. To find those accounts, run this query:

```
SELECT user,host FROM mysql.user WHERE host='%';
```

You should also be cognizant of how MySQL user authentication occurs.

According to [**MySQL 5.0 Certification Study Guide pages 486,487**](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0672328127), the following describes mysql's authentication algorithm:

> There are two stages of client access control:
>
> In the first stage, a client attempts to connect and the server either
>   accepts or rejects the connection. For the attempt to succeed, some
>   entry in the user table must match the host from which the client
>   connects, the username, and the password.
>
> In the second stage (which occurs only if a client has already
>   connected sucessfully), the server checks every query it receives from
>   the client to see whether the client has sufficient privileges to
>   execute it.
>
> The server matches a client against entries in the grant tables based
>   on the host from which the client connects and the user the client
>   provides. However, it's possible for more than one record to match:
>
> Host values in grant tables amy be specified as patterns contains
>   wildcard values. If a grant table contains entris from
>   `myhost.example.com`, `%.example.com`, `%.com`, and `%`, all of them
>   match a client who connects from `myhost.example.com`.
>
> Patterns are not allowed for the User values in grant table entries,
>   but a username may be given as an empty string to specify an anonymous
>   user. The empty string matches any username and thus effectively acts
>   as a wildcard.
>
> When the Host and the User values in more than one user table record
>   match a client, the server must decide which one to use. It does this
>   by sorting records with the most specific Host and User column values
>   first, and choosing the matching record that occurs first in the
>   sorted list, Sorting take place as follows:
>
> In the Host Column, literal values such as `localhost`, `127.0.0.1`,
>   and `myhost.example.com` sort ahead of values such as `%.example.com`
>   that have pattern characters in them. Pattern values are sorted
>   according to how specific they are. For example, `%.example.com` is
>   more specific than `%.com`, which is more specific than `%`.
>
> In the User column, non-blank usernames sort ahead of blank usernames.
>   That is, non-anonymous users sort ahead of anonymous users.
>
> The server performs this sorting when it starts. It reads the grant
>   tables into memory, sorts them, and uses the  in-memory copies for
>   access control.

### SUMMARY

If you have any users that must have remote access, change the host of each user that has `%` into the public IP you will be connecting from.

For example, if the user `myuser` must connect from 208.21.42.184, replace the host like this

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET host='208.21.42.184' WHERE user='myuser' AND host='%';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

You should also be checking for the presence of any test databases. The presence of test databases. ***Any database named `test` or whose first five(5) characters are `test_` need to be renamed immediately*** !!! [**I wrote an earlier post on how and why**](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/13361/877).