# What are the default settings for accessing MySQL remotely?

Tags: mysql

What is default settings in MYSQL for Remote access?

In CentOS the file `/etc/my.cnf` does not have `skip-networking` or `bind-address`. MySQL Version is 5.5, does it mean the server is enabled for remote access?

MySQL restart failed after adding `skip-networking` and `bind-address=127.0.0.1` in my `my.cnf file`, so how can I disable remote access?

## my.cnf

```
[mysqld]
skip-networking
innodb_file_per_table=1
innodb_file_format=barracuda
innodb_strict_mode=1
default-storage-engine=MyISAM
long_query_time=5
log_slow_queries=ON
thread_cache_size=32
key_buffer_size=64M
table_open_cache=1000
max_connections=300
query_cache_type=2
query_cache_limit=32M
query_cache_size=160M
max_heap_table_size=256M
tmp_table_size=256M
wait_timeout=360
interactive_timeout=360
max_allowed_packet=16M
sort_buffer_size=8M
innodb_buffer_pool_size=256M
innodb_log_file_size=64M
```

Comment: I removed bind-address=127.0.0.1 from my.cnf to restart mysql with out errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will have to resort to removing remote access from the MySQL users themselves.

To find out who has remote access, run this

```
SELECT user,host from mysql.user
WHERE host NOT IN ('localhost','127.0.0.1');
```

This will show you everyone that can login to MySQL from specific access points as well as broader network specifications.

You could run the utility [mysql_secure_installation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-secure-installation.html) which do the following:

- You can set a password for root accounts.
- You can remove root accounts that are accessible from outside the local host.
- You can remove anonymous-user accounts.
- You can remove the test database (which by default can be accessed by all users, even anonymous users), and privileges that permit anyone to access databases with names that start with test_. (I posted a [**question**](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/13361/877) and [**answer**](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/13363/877) about this weird aspect).

## UPDATE 2013-07-02 13:11 EDT

I see you have `skip-networking` in the `my.cnf` and you removed `bind-address=127.0.0.1`. I don't think the two options belong together. Why?

The option [**skip-networking**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_skip-networking) disables TCP/IP. Using `127.0.0.1` as a [**bind-address**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_bind-address) implies TCP/IP. The two can never really mix. They are meant to be mutually exclusive. Use one or the other, not both at the same time. This makes sense because when you read the MySQL Documentation for [**skip-networking**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_skip-networking) and [**bind-address**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_bind-address), one does not mention the other.

Comment: if I use bind-address=127.0.0.1 in my my.cnf file to disable remote access, my MYSQL server is not restarting properly, what may be the reason? Adv thanks

Comment: Please post the my.cnf into the body of your question.

Comment: I have been posted my my.cnf