# Annonymous user has no privileges, but still able to show databases?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, permissions

Output of `SHOW GRANTS FOR ''@'localhost';`

`GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO ''@'localhost'`

However, when I log in using my default user account, which is later defaulted to an annonymous account by mySQL as shown below :

Output of `SELECT USER(),CURRENT_USER();`

```
+------------------+-------------------+
| USER()           | CURRENT_USER()    |
| dukn@localhost   | @localhost        |
+------------------+-------------------+
```

I can still do `show databases;` using @localhost. Why is this so ?

**UPDATE:**

Output of @@version :  `5.5.34-0ubuntu0.13.10.1`

Output of show grants while logged in as dukn@localhost : `GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO ''@'localhost'`

Comment: Are you saying you can run `SHOW DATABASES;` *and* see the  list of databases?  Or does it return nothing (but no error)?  Please add the output of `SHOW GRANTS;` *while logged in* as the user in question (as opposed to `SHOW GRANTS FOR...`).  Also please include `SELECT @@VERSION;`.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Yes, `SHOW DATABASES;` still shows the list of databases. Updated the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just ran this in MySQL 5.6.15 on my Windows 8 machine

```
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 4
Server version: 5.6.15 MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2013, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> select user(),current_user();
+----------------+----------------+
| user()         | current_user() |
+----------------+----------------+
| ODBC@localhost | @localhost     |
+----------------+----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> show databases;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| test               |
+--------------------+
2 rows in set (0.05 sec)

mysql>
```

Then, I logged into MySQL as redwards@localhost

```
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 5
Server version: 5.6.15 MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2013, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> select user(),current_user();
+--------------------+--------------------+
| user()             | current_user()     |
+--------------------+--------------------+
| redwards@localhost | redwards@localhost |
+--------------------+--------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> show databases;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| mysql              |
| performance_schema |
| test               |
+--------------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

What is the difference? An anonymous user can still execute `SHOW DATABASES;` but can only see information_schema (contains metadata only anonymous users can see). Why can the database `test` be seen? The table `mysql.db` allows test databases to be visible to everyone (See my question [MySQL : Why are there "test" entries in mysql.db?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/13361/mysql-why-are-there-test-entries-in-mysql-db) and [the answer I posted](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/13363/877))