# Help granting MySQL user privileges to one database only

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6

I'm having trouble granting permissions to a user on a single database. The user can't log in once I've done what's below. I'm running as root on MySQL 5.6

```
SELECT USER(),CURRENT_USER();
+----------------+----------------+
| USER()         | CURRENT_USER() |
+----------------+----------------+
| root@localhost | root@localhost |
+----------------+----------------+
```

Here's my database list (abridged)

```
list databases;

+-------------------------+
| Database                |
+-------------------------+
| hr_test                 |
```

First I create the new user

```
CREATE USER 'hr_test_user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

This seems to work (i'm not showing all the other users).

```
select * from information_schema.user_privileges;
| 'hr_test_user'@'localhost'                | def           | USAGE                   | NO           |
```

I then try to grant privileges to one database

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON hr_test.* TO 'hr_test_user'@'localhost'  IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

When I run "select * from information_schema.user_privileges;" nothing has changed, the user just has "usage". When the user tries to log in they get rejected.

However when I grant wide privileges as such the line below I get all privileges.

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'hr_test_user'@'localhost'  IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

The table shows these privileges (abridged)

```
| 'hr_test_user'@'localhost'                | def           | SELECT                  | NO           |
| 'hr_test_user'@'localhost'                | def           | INSERT                  | NO           |
| 'hr_test_user'@'localhost'                | def           | UPDATE                  | NO           |
| 'hr_test_user'@'localhost'                | def           | DELETE                  | NO           |
| 'hr_test_user'@'localhost'                | def           | CREATE                  | NO           |
| 'hr_test_user'@'localhost'                | def           | DROP                    | NO           |
```

I can drop the user and do it again, but I get the same result. I've done this before to create other users with no problems, I even recorded exactly what I did last time when it worked, so I'm puzzled.

It looks like I'm identifying the database I want to grant privileges on incorrectly, but I can't spot what I'm doing wrong. Can anyone else?

**Update**
Based on the answer from @SQL.RK I recreated the user with the privileges required, then ran this additional command

```
select * from information_schema.SCHEMA_PRIVILEGES;
```

This is the relevant part of the output

```
| 'hr_test_user'@'localhost'     | def           | hr_test            | SELECT                  | NO           |
| 'hr_test_user'@'localhost'     | def           | hr_test            | INSERT                  | NO           |
| 'hr_test_user'@'localhost'     | def           | hr_test            | UPDATE                  | NO           |
| 'hr_test_user'@'localhost'     | def           | hr_test            | DELETE                  | NO           |
| 'hr_test_user'@'localhost'     | def           | hr_test            | CREATE                  | NO           |
```

That looks fine to me. I tried to log in and it worked, when I did what seems exactly the same as before!

**Theory**
I copied this text out of my password manager where I keep database authentication information and the commands I use to create databases. I noticed when I copied out of there I didn't have to hit enter in MySQL. I wonder if the grant command wasn't actually executing.

I don't think this is it because "grant all privileges" was also in there and that worked. I'm a bit stumped. I won't mark this as answered just yet, I'd like to hear any theories or hear if I've done anything clearly incorrect first.

**Update 2**

```
show grants;
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for hr_test_user@localhost                                                             |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'hr_test_user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD <secret>          |
| GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE ON `hr_test`.* TO 'hr_test_user'@'localhost' |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Log in with that user and run `SHOW GRANTS;`. What's the output ???

Comment: Thanks @RolandoMySQLDBA, I've edited the question with that information. That "usage" access on *.* is a bit puzzling, but the user can't access any of my other application databases. They can "use" access an old "test" database ("use test") , but it has no tables so that might be why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comment, I say don't worry.

The output for `SHOW GRANTS;` is correct. The user `hr_test_user` can only access the `hr_test` database, and no other database.

Why would the output be split like that ?

- `mysql.user` stores the user,host,password of `hr_test_user`@`localhost`
- `mysql.db` stores the privileges of `hr_test_user`@`localhost`

You will have to run the grants for each individual database to access them.

For example, to add grants for `db1` and `db2`, you would run

```
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE ON `db1`.* TO 'hr_test_user'@'localhost';
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE ON `db2`.* TO 'hr_test_user'@'localhost';
```

Now, I have some bad news. If you have a test database, you should drop it. Do not create any test databases because mysql installations will secretly give away full access to a test database that is named `test` or any database name starting with `test_`. I wrote all about that in [MySQL : Why are there "test" entries in mysql.db?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/13361/mysql-why-are-there-test-entries-in-mysql-db)

If you need any test databases, don't name it `test` and don't name it with `test_` as prefix.

Comment: Interesting, thank Rolando :) Looks like things are ok now. I'm still really puzzled about why this didn't work when I first tried them 12 hours ago, but running the same commands worked now. Quite puzzling, and I don't know enough about MySQL to investigate myself. I might have to do some reading.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the table information_schema.SCHEMA_PRIVILEGES. Refer [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/schema-privileges-table.html).