# Backup and restore "mysql" database

Tags: mysql, backup, mysqldump

I use the following command to backup some normal databases:

```
mysqldump --host=host --user=user --password=passwd --result-file=result.sql -R --single-transaction database_name
```

My question is : do I need to also dump the "mysql" database ? 
Note that I will create new users for each database after "restoring" them. So I don't need the "mysql" database for user information.

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

Most people that perform mysqldumps just use the `--all-databases` option. That will include the `mysql` database. There are two schools of thought as to whether one should include the `mysql` database.

## Why not to include *mysql* ???

When you mysqldump the mysql schema, you should make yourself aware of differences in MySQL versions, particularly the mysql.user table.

- In MySQL 5.0, mysql.user has 37 columns
- In MySQL 5.1, mysql.user has 39 columns
- In MySQL 5.5, mysql.user has 42 columns

Restoring a mysqldump from one version can result in certain privileges disappearing when restored :

Make sure you handle dumping user grants as a special script. There are two methods for this:

### METHOD #1 : Use [**pt-show-grants**](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.0/pt-show-grants.html)

This Percona Toolkit program move print out the User Permission in Pure SQL. You could run the result output into a Text File. Then, execute the Text File in MySQL 5.5.24. End of Story.

```
pt-show-grants ... > MySQLUserGrants.sql
```

### METHOD #2 : Emulate pt-show-grants

I made my own technique for pt-show-grants

```
mysql -hhostaddr -umyuserid -pmypassword --skip-column-names -A -e"SELECT CONCAT('SHOW GRANTS FOR ''',user,'''@''',host,''';') FROM mysql.user WHERE user<>''" | mysql -hhostaddr -umyuserid -pmypassword --skip-column-names -A | sed 's/$/;/g' > MySQLUserGrants.sql
```

I have discussed this before

- `Apr 09, 2012` : [Mysql users deleted](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/16215/mysql-users-deleted/16261#16261)
- `Apr 12, 2012` : [Cannot GRANT privileges as root](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/16397/cannot-grant-privileges-as-root/16441#16441)
- `Jun 13, 2012` : [Fastest way to move a database from one server to another](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/19219/fastest-way-to-move-a-database-from-one-server-to-another/19220#19220)

## Why include *mysql* ???

The only case for which you can mysqldump the `mysql` schema is to restore it to the same version of `mysql`

## UPDATE 2014-12-30 17:42 EST

My original answer covered just the MySQL Grants since this particular aspect of the mysql schema is the easiest to break and overlook.

There are other reasons not to just backup the mysql schema unless it is necessary

- If you want to retain the timestamps for all Stored Procedures, you can mysqldump the mysql.proc table by itself and load it. You can also just copy the `proc.frm`, `proc.MYD`, and `proc.MYI` then reload it by copying it back into the mysql subsfolder and runninf `FLUSH TABLES;`
- If you use table based logging for the general log (mysql.general_log) and slow log (mysql.slow_log), you do not want to backup these logs and move them to another server where the logs do not semantically apply. It is your choice if you want to restore them.
- If you set any timezone info in the mysql, be very careful if you do not want to restore the mysql schema in a data center that is in another timezone.

If you want to be careful about what you want to backup and restore in the mysql schema, you should mysqldump the mysql schema in a separate file.

The number of tables in the mysql schema, as well as the number of columns, will vary from version to version. So, you should login to mysql and run

```
SHOW TABLES FROM mysql;
```

The list of tables may not include events (like MySQL 5.0), may not have InnoDB system tables (like MySQL 5.6 has), may not include tablespace grants (like MySQL 5.6), and so forth. Sp, if you feel you must backup the mysql schema, you be very conservative (ok very picky and careful) about what tables you truly need to backup from the mysql schema.

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating new users and the like on the new system, then their is no need to backup the MySQL database.

Wish I had some documentation to show you, but it's quite difficult to Google MySQL database, as all the results are purely to do with the MySQL system, and not the database created in itself.

Answer (score 0):

**No need for MYSQL or any table other than your database.**

Because, mysql db contains information about users, help, host, servers, time-zone, etc.. which is totally not needed as you are gonna make new users.

*FYI : there are more two tables, that you might not wanting, and which you should not back up.
`performance_schema` and `information_schema`*

Answer (score 0):

You could skip the mysql database on your backup process if you don't care about user accounts but on target instance you should have a mysql db to start MySQL Server...

Max