# Proper procedure for migrating a MySQL database to another Debian machine?

Tags: mysql, mysqldump, linux, migration

I have one server running an older Debian version with MySQL 5.x and a newer Debian server, also running MySQL.

I've created a backup of all databases on  the first server like so:

```
mysqldump -uuser -ppass --all-databases > dump.sql
```

On the other server,  I did a:

```
mysql -uuser -ppass < dump.sql
```

At first, everything seemed great. I could browse my databases in phpMyAdmin, but as soon as I tried logging in again, it failed. Turns out, my `root` password had been overwritten with the one from the older database.

I wanted to reset it, but in order to do so, I would have needed to start `mysqld_safe`. Which I couldn't because the password for the `debian-sys-maint` user had been overwritten as well in the database. When I thought all hell had broken loose, I somehow reset both the `root` and `debian-sys-maint` passwords to the original values of the new server, and I managed to revert to a clean state.

Since I obviously don't want to go down *that* road again, here's the question(s):

- Was I right with my approach of using a complete `--all-databases` dump?
- Was there something I needed to do in advance to reading in that dump to prevent this desaster from happening? Or even before creating the dump?

If I'm going about this the wrong way:

- What is the proper procedure for migrating *all* databases and their users to another server?

Note that I'm not that experienced with MySQL and server administration at all, so I might be missing something obvious. All the tutorials and how-tos I've found never mention anything like this and just talk about importing the complete dump.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand: you dumped from the old and imported it in the new and expected the new passwords to remain untouched, but they were overwritten?

Comment: I didn't particularly expect the root and Debian admin user passwords to be overwritten, no. The other privileges, yes, but not those that you need to access and administer your MySQL installation in the first place, because… well, you'd lock yourself out. In hindsight, this was a bad idea, but from all I've read before there were no warnings about a situation like this.

Comment: Question: Was the version of MySQL the same on both machines? If not, what was version of MySQL you mysqldump'd, and what was the version of MySQL you loaded ?

Comment: It wasn't the same version exactly. 5.0.51a on the old and 5.1.66 on the new one. @rol

Comment: Ouch !!! You just steamrolled the mysql schema. See my post : http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/31023/877

Comment: It seems so… Okay, so basically I should use `pt-show-grants`, remove the `root` and `debian-sys-maint` info from that output, and then use this to migrate? And from the other dumpfile, remove any mention of the `user` table? @rol

Comment: I believe you should run mysql_upgrade package to fix `mysql.user` table because some privs are now physically misaliagned ( See my post http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/16441/877 )

Answer (score 2):

That is a normal procedure for setting up a new server from old database, so there's nothing wrong with this. Probably the reason there is no mention of the passwords getting overwritten is admins know the old passwords so can easily update them on the new server.

One thing you can do is modify the dumpfile to use the new passwords for root and your Debian admin user prior to loading it into the new server.