# In place upgrade from MySQL 5.5 to 5.6.11 removes all users from user table

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, upgrade, mysql-5.6

On Windows, I upgraded from 5.1 to 5.5 no problem.

1. Copied my 5.1 data folder into my 5.5 instance
2. Started mysqld skipping grants
3. Ran mysql_upgrade

All good, but going from 5.5 to 5.6:

1. Copied 5.5 data folder to 5.6 instance
2. Started mysqld skipping grants
3. Ran mysql_upgrade

but I get:

```
C:\Users\QAdmin>mysql_upgrade
Looking for 'mysql.exe' as: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin\mysql.exe
Looking for 'mysqlcheck.exe' as: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin\mysqlcheck.exe
Running 'mysqlcheck' with connection arguments: "--port=3306"
Running 'mysqlcheck' with connection arguments: "--port=3306"
mysql.user_info                                    OK
Running 'mysql_fix_privilege_tables'...
Running 'mysqlcheck' with connection arguments: "--port=3306"
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin\mysqlcheck.exe: Got error: 1130: Host 'localhost' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server when trying to connect
FATAL ERROR: Upgrade failed
```

If I look at the `mysql.user` table it is completely empty.

- Has anyone seen this or know what is going on?
- During the "upgrade"  the user table gets erased and when it tries to connect it can't?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a new problem

- `Feb 07, 2007` : [Upgrading from MySQL 3.23 to 5](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Database/MySQL/Q_22154391.html)
- `Oct 26, 2010` : [Upgrading from MySQL 4.1 to 5](http://full-adjusted.rssing.com/chan-1159747/all_p16.html#item306)

On May 11, 2007. someone had "fun" with this upgrading MySQL 4.1 to 5.0.41. [Notice his comment](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en//windows-upgrading.html) (Look for `Posted by Phil Collett on May 11 2007 7:11pm` in the Post):

> I had some fun upgrading from mysql-4.1.15-win32 (mysql 4.1) to
>   mysql-5.0.41-win32. I figured I would write down what I did to save
>   people time. The permissions table thing is still tricky. I used the
>   no-installer to get the version 5 mysql. Then I just swapped the
>   installs as I had done in the past. when I relaunched mysql
>   (mysql5/bin/mysqld-nt --console) I kept getting Error 1130 [HYO 000x]
>   cannot logon locally errors. So this was the mysql permission tables
>   upgrade problem. After attacking the upgrade from a few differnt
>   angles I found the way that worked for me. This is detailed below.
>
> The upgrade took me 15 minutes after I had my plan.
>
> 1. download mysql 5 no install.
> 2. unzip it.
> 3. export you mysql.db and mysql.user tables using whatever tool you use (make import of old users permissions and table rights) so you get
>      something like (I used EMS extract)...
>
> use mysql; INSERT INTO `db` (`Host`, `Db`, `User`, `Select_priv`,
>   `Insert_priv`, `Update_priv`, `Delete_priv`, `Create_priv`,
>   `Drop_priv`, `Grant_priv`, `References_priv`, `Index_priv`,
>   `Alter_priv`, `Create_tmp_table_priv`, `Lock_tables_priv`) VALUES 
>   ('%','Database','Table','Y','Y','Y','Y','N','N','N','N','N','N','N','N'),
>   next rec.. next rec ....); COMMIT;
>   #
>
> ## Data for the `db` table (LIMIT 0,500)
>
> ## INSERT INTO `user` (`Host`, `User`, `Password`, `Select_priv`, `Insert_priv`, `Update_priv`, `Delete_priv`, `Create_priv`,
>
> `Drop_priv`, `Reload_priv`, `Shutdown_priv`, `Process_priv`,
>   `File_priv`, `Grant_priv`, `References_priv`, `Index_priv`,
>   `Alter_priv`, `Show_db_priv`, `Super_priv`, `Create_tmp_table_priv`,
>   `Lock_tables_priv`, `Execute_priv`, `Repl_slave_priv`,
>   `Repl_client_priv`, `ssl_type`, `ssl_cipher`, `x509_issuer`,
>   `x509_subject`, `max_questions`, `max_updates`, `max_connections`)
>   VALUES 
>   ('%','parts','old-encrypted-password','N','N','N','N','N','N','N','N','N','N','N','N','N','N','N','N','N','N','N','N','N','','','','',0,0,0),
>   ...next rec.....; commit;
>
> save as a text file somewhere.
>   4. open a command window and end the mysql service, if you run as service.
>   5. go to mysql install folder/bin and unregister whatever mysql daemon you are using c:/mysql/bin/mysqld-nt --remove
>
> 6. zip up all your old mysql (basedir and DataDir) for  backup and later use.
> 7. find all your old my.cnf and my.ini files that were left over from previous installs and put them in you backup folder with the other
>      ziped folders so the new install can't see them.
> 8. place mysql 5's unzipped stuff where ever you want it to run from (mine is c:/mysql5.
> 9. just let iot use the mysql and test databases at first to get mysql5 running.
> 10. Set up your my.ini file for mysql 5 and just leave it in the mysql directory (none in %sysroot% any more I guess.
> 11. start mysql5 in console c:/mysql5/bin/mysqld-nt --console.
> 12. Try to log into the console with a blank root password (since this is a fresh install).
> 13. assuming you got this far, type "SHOW DATABASES;" in mysql. Should only be Mysql and Test.
> 14. Copy you old databases except of course the 4.1 mysql and 4.1 test dbs (if it is still there) to you c:/mysql5/data/ directory.
> 15. check in mysql console if they can be seen by running "Show Databases;" again.
> 16. Hopefully that worked, no import your old db and user permission from the sql file you made earlier.  in mysql console: SOURCE
>       "c:/your-file-path.txt"; that should bring in your old user and
>       password in the old format.
> 17. check if you import worked by selecting from users (use mysql; select * from user;)
> 18. I was fine at this point besides the old password format, so I ran the Mysql_upgrade.exe file that is mentioned in here a million times,
>       but omly worked for me this way.
> 19. I ran mysql_upgrade from a batch file: C:\mysql5\bin\mysql_upgrade.exe --datadir=c:/mysql5/data/
>       --basedir=c:/mysql5/ -u root > @pause
> 20. a whole bunch of output about bad table struct, 4.1 style passwords and duplicate columns. when it finsihed I ran it again, and
>       only got the dup column warnings which can be ignored. Then I ran it
>       again just for fun.
> 21. at this point all the db's are in the right structure, my logins all worked.
> 22. closed my console session running mysql, closed my console window mysql was running in (--mysqld-nt --console) and moved my data
>       directory back to which it came (personal choice).
> 23. Checked my cofig file (in mysql base dir ...c:/mysql5/my.ini) using "c/mysql5/mysqld-nt --print-defaults" and they looked fine,
>       changed my datadir="x:/path", and re-ran the --print-defaults.
> 24. I then reinstalled the msyql as a service with the my.ini file still only in my basedir (c:/mysql5/bin/mysqld-nt --install), and
>       started mysql (net start mysql) or services gui.
> 25. Last thing, make the root user a password, easily crackable of course like a bad word (don't really do this, but do make a password).
>
> Hope that saves somebody else some time.
>   -Phil Citrus Motors

Right now, you say that `mysql.user` is empty. Ugh !!! This means you will have to run mysql with `skip-grant-tables` in `my.ini` for now.

Here is the next things you can do: Find out how many columns are in `mysql.user`

Run this query

```
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_schema='mysql' AND table_name='user';
```

If you get 43, the `mysql.user` table is MySQL 5.6 ready

If you get 42, the `mysql.user` table is MySQL 5.5 ready

I wrote about this before : [Cannot GRANT privileges as root](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/16397/cannot-grant-privileges-as-root/16441#16441)

## Try This #1

Simply copy back the mysql.user table from the MySQL 5.5. dataset. That would mean copying

- `user.frm`
- `user.MYD`
- `user.MYI`

from the mysql subfolder of MySQL 5.5 datadir into the mysql subfolder of MySQL 5.5 datadir.

Then, rerun the upgrade and go from there.

## Try This #2

If you do not want to touch the mysql_upgrade, then add the user

```
REPLACE INTO mysql.user SET
                  Host = 'root',
                  User = 'localhost',
              Password = PASSWORD('whateverpasswordiwant'),
             Select_priv = 'Y',
             Insert_priv = 'Y',
             Update_priv = 'Y',
             Delete_priv = 'Y',
             Create_priv = 'Y',
               Drop_priv = 'Y',
             Reload_priv = 'Y',
           Shutdown_priv = 'Y',
            Process_priv = 'Y',
               File_priv = 'Y',
              Grant_priv = 'Y',
         References_priv = 'Y',
              Index_priv = 'Y',
              Alter_priv = 'Y',
            Show_db_priv = 'Y',
              Super_priv = 'Y',
   Create_tmp_table_priv = 'Y',
        Lock_tables_priv = 'Y',
            Execute_priv = 'Y',
         Repl_slave_priv = 'Y',
        Repl_client_priv = 'Y',
        Create_view_priv = 'Y',
          Show_view_priv = 'Y',
     Create_routine_priv = 'Y',
      Alter_routine_priv = 'Y',
        Create_user_priv = 'Y',
              Event_priv = 'Y',
            Trigger_priv = 'Y',
  Create_tablespace_priv = 'Y',
                ssl_type = '',
              ssl_cipher = '',
             x509_issuer = '',
            x509_subject = '',
           max_questions = 0,
             max_updates = 0,
         max_connections = 0,
    max_user_connections = 0
;
```

Logout of mysql, remove `skip-grant-tables` from my.ini. Restart

## CAVEAT

Personally, I hate mysql_upgrade. I actually dump the grants as SQL

Here is how to do it for Windows

```
set MYSQL_CONN=-uroot -prootpassword
mysql %MYSQL_CONN% -ANe"SELECT CONCAT('SHOW GRANTS FOR ''',user,'''@''',host,''';') FROM mysql.user WHERE user<>''" > GetGrants.sql
mysql %MYSQL_CONN% -AN < GetGrants.sql > MySQLUserGrants.sql
```

then in a newer installation. I execute the MySQLUserGrants.sql and all necessary columns are populated using SQL GRANTs only.

I actually wrote about this technique before

- `Jul 26, 2011` : [Restoring an old backup to latest MySQL release](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/4114/restoring-an-old-backup-to-latest-mysql-release/4127#4127)
- `Sep 23, 2011` : [Anyone have issues with a MySQL 5.1 to 5.5 in-place Upgrade in Production?](https://serverfault.com/a/314995/69271)
- `Dec 24, 2012` : [Backup and restore "mysql" database](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/30974/backup-and-restore-mysql-database/31023#31023)
- `Mar 24, 2013` : [MySQL export user with semi-colon ";" on the end](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/37422/mysql-export-user-with-semi-colon-on-the-end/37477#37477)

Comment: Good Stuff!  Thanks for the info, it is my afternoon project!

Comment: @peter  IT WORKED!!!  Thanks a million.  The mysql_upgrade had created the new columns in the mysql db and I added root and then used the info you provided to recreate my grants(very helpful).  I'm not positive this is the case, but root could not "Grant all" at first (error:1045 access denied) so I made the mysql.user table look like the vanilla 56 install in regard to entries for root.  Meaning I duplicated the entry for root in mysql.user and changed host from localhost to 127.0.0.1.

Comment: Question : Who is @peter ?

Comment: oops, I should never post without my glasses!!  Thanks again Rolando.  Now it is on to trying out replication with GTID's