# How to create root user after running mysql_install_db?

Tags: mysql, users

I'm installing MySQL on ubuntu and I changed the data directory. I created new data files using `mysql_install_db` command.

So now I need to access my database using `root` but it won't let me in. I tried starting the database by skipping the grant tables:

```
mysqld --skip-grant-tables --skip-networking &
```

Now I'm in, but the mysql.user table doesn't have a single row, which is logical after creating the data files from scratch, or isn't it ??

So I tried:

```
CREATE USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypass';
```

But it won't run because I'm running with `--skip-grant-tables` !

- So how can I create a `root` user from that point ?
- And how can I stop the started mysql instance I just started with `--skip-grant-tables` because it seems I always have to `killall mysqld` to do it !

Comment: What version of MySQL are you running ???

Answer (score 1):

There are two techniques

## TECHNIQUE #1 : Use an init file

```
INITFILE=/var/lib/mysql/init-file.sql
echo "SET @newpass = PASSWORD('mypass');" > ${INITFILE}
echo "CREATE USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY @newpass;" >> ${INITFILE}
chown mysql:mysql ${INITFILE}
service mysql stop
service mysql start --init-file=${INITFILE}
rm -f ${INITFILE}
```

## TECHNIQUE #2 : Inject User into mysql.user

With `--skip-grant-tables` enabled, run this:

```
REPLACE INTO mysql.user SET
                  Host = 'root',
                  User = 'localhost',
              Password = PASSWORD('whateverpasswordiwant'),
             Select_priv = 'Y',
             Insert_priv = 'Y',
             Update_priv = 'Y',
             Delete_priv = 'Y',
             Create_priv = 'Y',
               Drop_priv = 'Y',
             Reload_priv = 'Y',
           Shutdown_priv = 'Y',
            Process_priv = 'Y',
               File_priv = 'Y',
              Grant_priv = 'Y',
         References_priv = 'Y',
              Index_priv = 'Y',
              Alter_priv = 'Y',
            Show_db_priv = 'Y',
              Super_priv = 'Y',
   Create_tmp_table_priv = 'Y',
        Lock_tables_priv = 'Y',
            Execute_priv = 'Y',
         Repl_slave_priv = 'Y',
        Repl_client_priv = 'Y',
        Create_view_priv = 'Y',
          Show_view_priv = 'Y',
     Create_routine_priv = 'Y',
      Alter_routine_priv = 'Y',
        Create_user_priv = 'Y',
              Event_priv = 'Y',
            Trigger_priv = 'Y',
  Create_tablespace_priv = 'Y',
                ssl_type = '',
              ssl_cipher = '',
             x509_issuer = '',
            x509_subject = '',
           max_questions = 0,
             max_updates = 0,
         max_connections = 0,
    max_user_connections = 0
;
```

Then, restart mysql as usual.

See my post [In place upgrade from MySQL 5.5 to 5.6.11 removes all users from user table](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/41946/in-place-upgrade-from-mysql-5-5-to-5-6-11-removes-all-users-from-user-table/41947#41947)

Comment: Maybe the REPLACE statement has a small mistake. Consider the below corrections:
host='localhost', user='root'

Comment: Shouldn't I `GRANT` all rights  and `WITH GRANT` to root ? I had to do that to solve my problem, after inserting the root user in the `mysql.user` table.

Comment: Hi Rolando, regarding @Wagner's comment above, I converted it to a comment from an answer because it seems related to your answer?

Answer (score 0):

I've done the solutions mentioned above but I still, as `root` couldn't grant privileges to other users. This is how I did it:

1. After `INSERT`ing the root user manually into the `mysql.user` table
2. **GRANT ALL ON . TO 'root'@'localhost'; FLUSH PRIVILEGES; exit;**
3. killall mysqld

Without step #2, I couldn't create users nor grant them rights.