# All users are having NO Privileges in phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, windows, ddl

By mistake, I changed all the privileges of user 'root' in my MySQL Database. Not even a single privilege is having for that user. Now if I log in with another user I am able to access only one database. But I have nearly 25 databases created with 'root' user. If I want to access all other databases I need to GRANT Privileges for the root user again but all other users are not permitted to execute GRANT statement. So is there any way to grant permissions for the root user again. The all other Databases contained in my DB Server are very much important. So Please help in resolving this issue.

Comment: QUESTIONS : Are you willing to restart mysql twice ??? What version of MySQL are you using ???

Comment: I want to grant permissions to the root user Sir. All the permissions are removed by mistake. I am running on localhost, and with the OS Windows. Can you please guide me in resolving this Sir

Comment: So MySQL is running in Windows ???

Comment: yes sir................

Comment: Do you have `my.ini` ? What version of MySQL are you running (5.1, 5.5, 5.6) ?

Comment: Yes Sir, I have my.ini file. My MySQL Version is 5.6.16 Sir.....

Answer (score 1):

I have discussed situations like this before in these posts:

- `May 10, 2013` : [In place upgrade from MySQL 5.5 to 5.6.11 removes all users from user table](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/41946/in-place-upgrade-from-mysql-5-5-to-5-6-11-removes-all-users-from-user-table/41947#41947)
- `Sep 22, 2013` : [How to create root user after running mysql_install_db?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/50312/how-to-create-root-user-after-running-mysql-install-db/50317#50317)

In your case do this

## STEP #1

Add these lines just under the `[mysqld]` group header in `my.ini`

```
[mysqld]
skip-grant-tables
skip-networking
```

## STEP 2

Open Windows Command Line as Administrator, and reboot MySQL Service

```
C:\> net stop mysql
C:\> net start mysql
```

## STEP 3

You can login to MySQL

```
C:\> mysql <Hit Enter>
```

## STEP 4

From the mysql prompt, run this

```
SET @PasswordHash = PASSWORD('whateverpasswordiwant');
REPLACE INTO mysql.user SET
                  Host = 'root',
                  User = 'localhost',
              Password = @PasswordHash,
             Select_priv = 'Y',
             Insert_priv = 'Y',
             Update_priv = 'Y',
             Delete_priv = 'Y',
             Create_priv = 'Y',
               Drop_priv = 'Y',
             Reload_priv = 'Y',
           Shutdown_priv = 'Y',
            Process_priv = 'Y',
               File_priv = 'Y',
              Grant_priv = 'Y',
         References_priv = 'Y',
              Index_priv = 'Y',
              Alter_priv = 'Y',
            Show_db_priv = 'Y',
              Super_priv = 'Y',
   Create_tmp_table_priv = 'Y',
        Lock_tables_priv = 'Y',
            Execute_priv = 'Y',
         Repl_slave_priv = 'Y',
        Repl_client_priv = 'Y',
        Create_view_priv = 'Y',
          Show_view_priv = 'Y',
     Create_routine_priv = 'Y',
      Alter_routine_priv = 'Y',
        Create_user_priv = 'Y',
              Event_priv = 'Y',
            Trigger_priv = 'Y',
  Create_tablespace_priv = 'Y',
                ssl_type = '',
              ssl_cipher = '',
             x509_issuer = '',
            x509_subject = '',
           max_questions = 0,
             max_updates = 0,
         max_connections = 0,
    max_user_connections = 0
;
REPLACE INTO mysql.user SET
                  Host = 'root',
                  User = '127.0.0.1',
              Password = @PasswordHash,
             Select_priv = 'Y',
             Insert_priv = 'Y',
             Update_priv = 'Y',
             Delete_priv = 'Y',
             Create_priv = 'Y',
               Drop_priv = 'Y',
             Reload_priv = 'Y',
           Shutdown_priv = 'Y',
            Process_priv = 'Y',
               File_priv = 'Y',
              Grant_priv = 'Y',
         References_priv = 'Y',
              Index_priv = 'Y',
              Alter_priv = 'Y',
            Show_db_priv = 'Y',
              Super_priv = 'Y',
   Create_tmp_table_priv = 'Y',
        Lock_tables_priv = 'Y',
            Execute_priv = 'Y',
         Repl_slave_priv = 'Y',
        Repl_client_priv = 'Y',
        Create_view_priv = 'Y',
          Show_view_priv = 'Y',
     Create_routine_priv = 'Y',
      Alter_routine_priv = 'Y',
        Create_user_priv = 'Y',
              Event_priv = 'Y',
            Trigger_priv = 'Y',
  Create_tablespace_priv = 'Y',
                ssl_type = '',
              ssl_cipher = '',
             x509_issuer = '',
            x509_subject = '',
           max_questions = 0,
             max_updates = 0,
         max_connections = 0,
    max_user_connections = 0
;
exit
```

## STEP 5

Remove `skip-grant-tables` and `skip-networking` from `my.ini`

## STEP 6

Restart MySQL

```
C:\> net stop mysql
C:\> net start mysql
```

## STEP 7

Try logging into MySQL

## GIVE IT A TRY !!!