# MySQL to MariaDB migration - user view breaks compatibility with backup-restores and replication

Tags: mysql, replication, backup, mariadb, restore

I am trying to migrate an Ubuntu 18.04-Server with Oracle's MySQL to a Ubuntu 22.04-Server with MariaDB 10.6.12. I've established a replication between the databases, which worked. Alone, the User management is entirely broken. Because Users are not longer a table but a view, the restore of the Mysqldump broke the original mariadb user view and created a table instead. Of course now almost all user accounts are broken.

How is the intended migration path for mission-critical Systems? I cannot afford significant downtimes, because that's why I create a replication during the migration process. Especially the passwords are an issue, as I cannot decrypt the original passwords (at least I hope so), so I cannot create the new Users with the CREATE USER statement. Whats the trick here?

Thank you very much, t2m

Comment: To clarify, the MySQL version is 5.7? MariaDB should be able to run on a Users table. If you look at [show create user](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-create-user.html) in MySQL output that should be transferable. [log_builtin_as_identified_by_password=ON](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-options-binary-log.html#sysvar_log_builtin_as_identified_by_password) may be needed. Did you take the mysqldump with MySQL or MariaDB's mysqldump executable? If you have time [online help](https://mariadb.zulipchat.com/) might be able to assist.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can dump the users and their grants separately

I wrote a post about this Mar 24, 2013 : [MySQL export user with semi-colon ";" on the end](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/37422/mysql-export-user-with-semi-colon-on-the-end/37477#37477)

What you do is dump all databases EXCEPT the mysql schema.

Load the grants dump into MariaDB and test connectivity. Then proceed with loading your data.

NOTE : I recently had an issue with a view in MySQL being ported to MariaDB. The SQL syntax of a query inthe view had to be changed. Please be onthe look out for that.