# Error log - What does this mean and what can I do about it?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, authentication

I have the following repeated errors in my error.log and I don't know what it means or what I should/can do about it:

> Access denied for user 'root'@'[some IP]' (using password: YES)

There are many different IPs showing in the [some IP] field.

I've been reading some security posts that recommend changing the root username to something else, is this something I should do here?

I am using MySQL 5.5.22

**I believe these are attempts to gain access to my database from hackers. I want to know what I can do to prevent the attempts. Most of the IPs are coming from China.**

Comment: I am sure this question has been asked before. http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/19212/error-in-login-in-with-root-user-in-new-mysql-server This may be due to the fact that you need to explicitly giver permissions for user@IP combo to log into MySQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My first answer is: why is your database even accessible from outside through the Internet? That network traffic really ought to be blocked by router Internet gateway router or firewall.

If you really need to allow some connections from the Internet to your database, then limit it to the valid IP address who should be connecting.

At this point that's not really a dba question but a network admin question.

Comment: +1 ... never a good idea for MySQL or any other service to be open to Internet without strong justification.  Also worth mentioning, given OP's version, is the security vulnerability in versions before 5.5.24 had a serious potential security flaw these attackers might be trying to exploit.  Official binaries were *not* affected but compiled-from-source and 3rd party builds may have been, depending on the underlying libraries used for the build: http://seclists.org/oss-sec/2012/q2/493

Answer (score -1):

Try the command below. Please review your options for security.

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'enter_password_here' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

This will basically allow the root account to log in from any machine, which is a security risk.

Specify the IP to restrict the connecting hosts.

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'[IP]' IDENTIFIED BY 'enter_password_here' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```