# Beginner problems administering users on mysql

Tags: mysql

Very new MySQL user here. Two questions for the community.

1. I seem to have created an account that I can't delete/drop.
2. I can't seem to get MySQL to actually require newly created accounts to require passwords even when I specify them during creation.

I ran `myisamchk` and corrupton doesn't seem to be an issue. Logs below.

```
mysql -u root -p
use mysql
select * from db\G;


*************************** 3. row ***************************
      Host: localhost
      Db: projectdb
      User: project
      Select_priv: Y
      Insert_priv: Y
      Update_priv: Y
      Delete_priv: Y
      Create_priv: Y
        Drop_priv: Y
       Grant_priv: Y
      References_priv: Y
       Index_priv: Y
       Alter_priv: Y
Create_tmp_table_priv: Y
 Lock_tables_priv: Y
 Create_view_priv: Y
   Show_view_priv: Y
Create_routine_priv: Y
 Alter_routine_priv: Y
     Execute_priv: Y
       Event_priv: Y
     Trigger_priv: Y

mysql> drop user project;
ERROR 1396 (HY000): Operation DROP USER failed for 'project'@'%'
```

~~~~~

```
CREATE USER project123 IDENTIFIED BY 'project123';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

GRANT ALL ON projectdb.* TO project123 IDENTIFIED BY 'project123';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

quit;
```

MySQL then proceeds to let me log in without a password.

```
macbook-pro-8: $ /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql -u project123
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Chris the folks on dba can help with this. It should be migrated automatically in a few. SO is for programming specifically, yours is more db administration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You obviously have anonymous users in mysql.user

Just run the following:

```
DELETE FROM mysql.user WHERE user='';
DELETE FROM mysql.user WHERE host='';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

I have past posts on this subject

- `Aug 14, 2011` : [Cannot drop anonymous user from mysql.user](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/4614/cannot-drop-anonymous-user-from-mysql-user/4615#4615)
- `Jan 18, 2012` : [MySQL error: Access denied for user 'a'@'localhost' (using password: YES)](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/10852/mysql-error-access-denied-for-user-alocalhost-using-password-yes/10897#10897)
- `Feb 17, 2012` : [MySQL : Why are there "test" entries in mysql.db?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/13361/mysql-why-are-there-test-entries-in-mysql-db/13363#13363)
- `Apr 09, 2012` : [Mysql users deleted](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/16215/mysql-users-deleted/16261#16261)
- `Jun 09, 2012` : [Why ALL PRIVILEGES ON `db`.* gives access to all databases?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/19008/why-all-privileges-on-db-gives-access-to-all-databases/19017#19017)
- `Jun 26, 2012` : [Best practices to secure mysql](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/19917/best-practices-to-secure-mysql/19956#19956)

Another observation: You tried to run `mysql> drop user project;`

By mysql's viewpoint, a user is identified as `user@host`

To see all defined users, please run this query:

```
SELECT CONCAT('''',user,'''@''',host,'''') MySQLUser FROM mysql.user;
```

You should see something like this:

```
+--------------------------+
| MySQLUser                |
+--------------------------+
| 'advdb'@'%'              |
| 'anadb'@'%'              |
| 'dmvadb'@'%'             |
| 'dmvanswers'@'%'         |
| 'dmvdb'@'%'              |
| 'dmvqnadb'@'%'           |
| 'icdb'@'%'               |
| 'jjohnston'@'%'          |
| 'localdb'@'%'            |
```

Thus, when you drop a user, it is best to use this style format as shown.

For example, to drop user `icdb`, you must run

```
DROP USER 'icdb'@'%';
```

Comment: Mysql still isn't requiring a password for newly created accounts even after deleting the blank accounts. Any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at your user table in mysql.

Try which may have some global DB privileges.

```
SELECT Host,User,Password FROM mysql.user;
```

I am sure this is not recommended anymore but I manually remove records from these tables and call

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Comment: Oddly user "project" doesn't show up on this list.

Comment: Is there a blank user maybe they are connecting with that?

Comment: Yes there is a blank user. Can't figure out how to delete it. drop user '' / ' ' don't work. Why would logging in as project123 default to a blank user? Also even if i log in with project123 with the -p flag and then just hit enter, it still logs the user in.

Comment: Getting to the limit of my knowledge but a user may be able to connect to the DB but not have any access to tables. I personally rely on contents of user table and not use finer grained control. I shall wait for a more informed mysql DBA to answer